# Select CASCADED dropdownlist item from sqldatareader

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, sqldatareader, cascadingdropdown

Okay , lets make it simple. I am extracting a user data and inserting it to different controls on a page with the below query :

the code-behind is like

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblUser where UserId='22'", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            txtOrganizationName.Text = rdr["OrgName"].ToString();
            ddlOrgState.SelectedIndex = ddlOrgState.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgState.Items.FindByText(rdr["State"].ToString()));
            ddlOrgCity.SelectedIndex = ddlOrgCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString()));
         }
    }
```

In the above code,

```
   txtOrganizationName.Text = rdr["OrgName"].ToString();
```

inserts the name of user to the textbox

```
   ddlOrgState.SelectedIndex = ddlOrgState.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgState.Items.FindByText(rdr["State"].ToString()));
```

selects the state of the user

BUT

```
  ddlOrgCity.SelectedIndex = ddlOrgCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString()));
```

does not select the city of the user.and that is my error and the issue with the code.

I have removed all the extra code from here to avoid confusion.
One important thing is : ddCity gets populated on SelectedIndexChanged event of ddlState.

If any code is required, Please let me know.

Comment: It isn't clear what the question is here. As a side note, you really should not use select *. And AddWithValue should also be avoided. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange - ddlOrgCity.SelectedIndex = ddlOrgCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString())); does not select any item in the city dropdown list

Comment: That does NOT make this any clearer. You have to remember I can't see your screen, I don't know your code, I don't know the project and I don't know what you are trying to do. All I know is the very brief amount of information you posted and that something isn't working. Your code seems to be a bit strange though because you are setting the current selected index in a loop. It seems that something is very wrong with your code but I don't know because I have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange - Updated my question

Comment: So what does ddlOrgCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlOrgCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString())) return? This is really pretty basic debugging of your code and it is nearly impossible to do remotely.